# aspx page continues loading and does not show in browser

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual studio 2010. When I start the page by right clicking on it in `VS2010` browser starts and `asp.net` server started to display. But the browser continues loading circle in browser tab and does not show page or any error message.

Comment: set a break point in your code behind and see what it happening.  Also hit F12 in chrome for example to see if there are javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks Adam. But nothing happen after breakpoint and there are no javascript errors. I am not sure, but might be this problem arise after upgrading (cloning) from normal hard disk to SSD hard disk.